# select sum qty from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL I have 4 tables:

```
 - product(id)
 - order(id)
 - order_detail_1(id, product_id, order_id, qty)
 - order_detail_2(id, product_id, order_id, qty)
```

I want to get the sum of the quantity of products sold from the 2 tables (order_detail_1, order_detail_2) grouping them by product

produt can existe in order_detail_1 and not in order_detail_2 and vice versa

i tested this query and it worked but I want a simpler query without the union and the subquery.

```
select tmp.product_id ,sum(tmp.qty)  from
(
(
select order_detail_1.product_id ,sum(order_detail_1.qty) 
from order_detail_1
    inner join order on order_detail_1.id_order = order.id
    where order_detail_1.product_id is not null
    group by order_detail_1.product_id
)
union all
(
select order_detail_2.product_id ,sum(order_detail_2.qty) 
from order_detail_2
    inner join order on order_detail_2.id_order = order.id
    where order_detail_2.product_id is not null
    group by order_detail_2.product_id
)
) tmp
group by tmp.product_id
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Seems like a db design issue. Why two different order_detail tables? (Create a view that does UNION ALL, and use that one instead.)

Comment: this query is a view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a product is in only one table, you can use `left join`:

```
select p.id, (coalesce(sum(od1.qty), 0) + coalesce(sum(od2.qty, 0))) as qty
from product p left join
     order_detail_1 od1
     on od1.product_id = p.id left join
     order_detail_2 od2
     on od2.product_id = p.id
group by p.id;
```

This formulation depends on the fact that the two tables are exclusion -- a product is in only one table.

EDIT:

If products can exist in both tables, then you need to aggregate them first:

```
select p.id, (coalesce(od1.qty, 0) + coalesce(od2.qty, 0)) as qty
from product p left join
     (select product_id, sum(qty) as qty
      from order_detail_1 od1
      group by product_id
     ) od1
     on od1.product_id = p.id left join
     (select product_id, sum(qty) as qty
      from order_detail_2 od2
      group by product_id
     ) od2
     on od2.product_id = p.id;
```

Comment: products can existe in both tables, but some products can existe in one table and not ine the other table

Comment: @sagi . . . "I want a simpler query without the union and the subquery".

Comment: Huh didn't read those words :). But still, I think he just meant a simper query because he uses `UNION` on identical queries , not necessarily to avoid UNION.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're not using `order` table other then checking if it exists, so you can use `EXISTS()`

```
SELECT p.product_id,sum(p.qty) as qty
FROM (SELECT product_id,qty,id_order FROM order_detail_1
      WHERE product_id IS NOT NULL
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT product_id,qty,id_order FROM order_detail_2
      WHERE product_id IS NOT NULL) p
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM order o 
             WHERE o.id = p.id_order)
GROUP BY p.product_id
```